How can two vectors who equal the same thing help form a basis?
There are vectors $v_1,v_2,...,v_{n-1}, u,w$ in $R^n$ space. u and w are linear combinations of $v_1...v_{n-1}$, like so:
$u=x_1v_1+...+x_{n-1}v_{n-1}$ with only one solution
$w=x_1v_1+...+x_{n-1}v_{n-1}$ has no solution.
How can I prove that ${v_1,...,v_{n-1},w}$ form a basis for $R^n$? If you subtract $u$ from $w$, you get that $u=w$, and I feel that makes no sense

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You are running into notational issues. Note that $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are unknowns. They are not fixed scalars, so you cannot "subtract $u$ from $w$".

You are running into notational issues that are confusing you.
It would be better to write the two conditions as follows:


There exists one and only one choice of scalars/solution $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{n-1}$ to $$u = \alpha_1v_1+\cdots+\alpha_{n-1}v_{n-1}.$$
There do not exist scalars $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_{n-1}$ such that $$w=\beta_1v_1+\cdots+\beta_{n-1}v_{n-1}.$$


You when you subtract $u$ from $w$ you do not get $0$, because there exist scalars that work for $u$ but no scalars that work for $w$.
As to proving what you want:

Use the condition on $u$ to conclude that $v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}$ are linearly independent. You can do this by showing that if they were linearly dependent, then there would be either no way, or strictly more than one way, to express a vector as a linear combination of $v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}$.

Then use the condition on $w$ to conclude that $w\notin\mathrm{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1})$, so together with part 1 you can conclude that $v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1},w$ are linearly independent. Then notice the dimension of your space.



The notation I gave is letter for letter what I saw.

@OscarYuleton. Still, $x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}$ are probably not meant to have the same values in the two equations. It's like writing "the equation $3x+4=5$ has one solution while the equation $3x^2-10=0$ has two solutions".

@OscarYuleton I did not say that you were miscopying. I said that it would be better if different letters had been used to avoid the confusion that you fell into.
